# git clone from debian virtualbox

Tags: git, vagrant

I have a vagrant box running with a git repository I can push to it from my host machine but I'm getting the following error when I try to clone from it.

```
$git clone git://staging.debian:joomz.git
```

gives me the following error

```
fatal: unable to connect to :
[0: fe80::357a:dab1:e84c:b263%25]: errno=No error
[1: fe80::8461:42b0:cd03:9b1%13]: errno=No error
[2: 192.168.56.1]: errno=No error
[3: 192.168.1.110]: errno=No error
```

As you see the ip `192.168.56.1` belongs to staging.debian(my VM) and the other one is my host. 
I am fairly new to git. Your help will be much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: add `-v` when cloning, to see more debug info. BTW: Are you using Gitolite, GitLab or sth? HTTP/HTTPS enabled?

Comment: No i'm not using any of those, I installed git from the debian repositories and nothing else. This is weird to me since I can do commits and push to the remote repo but cloning doesn't work. Do I need Gitolite for this? 
PS: I am fairly new to git.

Comment: Aha, that's what I was suspecting anyway. Good to see you figured out;-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it made me curious to look into it. :)

Comment: Post your own answer as a real answer instead of editing your question. If it's a real answer to a real question, it deserves to look like that, no matter who the author's of them are.

Comment: @desert69 my reputation was too low to answer my own question. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, since Git doesn't do access control I needed something like gitolite for that (or any other variant there's a lot of choices).

if you need help with that follow this guide: http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-8.html it's very easy to use. 
Cheers.